# Evaluate $\sum_{p=1}^{32}(3p+2)\Bigg(\sum_{q=1}^{10}\bigg(\sin\frac{2q\pi}{11}-i\cos\frac{2q\pi}{11}\bigg)\Bigg)^{p} $

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Evaluate $$\sum_{p=1}^{32}(3p+2)\Bigg(\sum_{q=1}^{10}\bigg(\sin\frac{2q\pi}{11}-i\cos\frac{2q\pi}{11}\bigg)\Bigg)^{p} $$

Comment: Why did you write a question exactly 2 minutes before writing the answer? Your LaTeX skill must be astounding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is $$\sum_{p=1}^{32}(3p+2)\Bigg(\sum_{q=1}^{10}(-i)\bigg(\cos\frac{2q\pi}{11}+i\sin\frac{2q\pi}{11}\bigg)\Bigg)^{p} $$ Here $$\sum_{q=1}^{10}(-i)\bigg(\cos\frac{2q\pi}{11}+i\sin\frac{2q\pi}{11}\bigg) $$
is $i$ and hence the sum $$\sum_{p=1}^{32}(3p+2)i^p $$ is evaluated by splitting into factors of $i,-1,-i,1$ as   $48(1-i)$.